# clickOnButton not working in Robotium

Tags: android, robotium

I have a very simple test: click on a Button, then display a message in a TextView showing the number of times that the button was clicked.  The test looks something like this:

```
@Smoke
public void testMessageIsUpdatedWhenButtonIsClicked() {
    _solo.clickOnButton(0);
    String displayedMessage = ((TextView) _solo.getView(R.id.messageTextView)).getText().toString();
    assertEquals("You clicked 1 times.", displayedMessage);
}
```

Now, when I run my test, the assert fails because the TextView is still displaying the original text from when the Activity started up.  It seems like the OnClickListener I created for the Button isn't getting called.

Has anybody else seen this problem?

Anything a guy can do to get around the issue?

Comment: Please see: "Why do text and button clicks get wrong?" http://code.google.com/p/robotium/wiki/QuestionsAndAnswers

Comment: I added the following to my AndroidManifest.xml on the test project:
 <uses-sdk android:targetSdkVersion="10" />

I then added this to the AndroidManifest.xml of my application:
 <supports-screens android:anyDensity="true"/> 

Still no luck. Should I file a bug report?

Comment: I have written a blog post to solve this problem. Here it is ..
http://chanakaudaya.blogspot.com/2012/03/robotium-button-click-not-working.html

Answer (score 4):

I was having a similar problem. In my case the problem was the keyboard! Because the keyboard was opened, robotium don't see the buttons: "OK" and "Cancel" . The solution: hide the keyboard and then press the button.

```
solo.enterText(0, "Hello!");
        solo.goBack(); //hide the keyboard
        solo.clickOnButton("\u041E\u041A");
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old, but I wanted to post because it has caused me lots of headache.

Tom, you mentioned in your comments:

> I added the following to my AndroidManifest.xml on the test project: `<uses-sdk android:targetSdkVersion="10" />` I then added this to the AndroidManifest.xml of my application: `<supports-screens android:anyDensity="true"/>` Still no luck. Should I file a bug report?

The solution actually is to add: `<uses-sdk android:targetSdkVersion="10" />` to the app you are testing NOT the actual test app. This one single change works for me. Now I can use `solo.clickButton("button text");` just like intended and not have to use a workaround.

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar problem. There was a button with the text "Games" on it, and I wanted to click it in my test case. After a lot of experimentation with the "solo". I found the below code to work:

```
solo.waitForDialogToClose(10000);
solo.clickOnButton("Games");
```

The problem I think in my case was that the button was getting clicked even before it was initialised and assigned the onClickListener.

Answer (score 0):

I often find that using

```
solo.clickOnText("buttonName");
```

rather than on the button seems to be a better approach. Robotium sometimes seems to have problems with clicking on buttons. If you prefer to use the button ID then I suggest the following:

```
solo.waitForIdleSync();
solo.clickOnButton(R.id.whatever);
```

Answer (score 0):

When you click on a button using solo. Use index based clicks instead of names or searching for a button. Index starts with 0.
`solo.clickOnButton(1);` 
solo clicks works best with indexes

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar problem. Unfortunately I was not able to force solo to click on button properly. However using adroid.test.TouchUtils solved my problems:

```
Button button = solo.getButton( 0 );
TouchUtils.clickView( this, button );
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Be so kind and explain why this solution is wrong. Thank you.